# Set optional fields in Spring Batch to LineMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

```
 private LineMapper<CSVFileRequest> lineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<CSVFileRequest> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
        lineTokenizer.setNames("caller_id","order_id","shipment","amount","acc_num","due_date");


        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<CSVFileRequest> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(CSVFileRequest.class);


        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        return lineMapper;

    }
```

How Can I set the custom fields, like In given CSV file, I don't have the other columns, in csv file there is only column, and here the data is to be inserted in two different tables, one belongs to caller_id, and other belongs to all other fields, now the question is how would I know, the other fields are given in csv file or not.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Need more clarity around what you exactly need to do

Answer (score 0):

you can set it by setIncluded

```
lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(new int[] {0,1,2});
```

Comment: No, in that thing, I would h've to specify columns, which are to be inserted, but I want to set fields as optional fields, like  if in request csv file there {0,2,3,4} fields are present, other are null, then lineMapper map those fields as null.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).